# How can I use RxJS BehaviorSubject to communicate numbers between components instead of strings

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am following this tutorial:

> https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#sibling-component-ts

To try to communicate a number between two components.
Following that tutorial, I only managed to communicate strings between components.

> This is parent-of-sibling.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-of-sibling',
  template: `
  <br>
  Here's the received message from sibling
  <br>

  {{message}}
  <br>

`,  styleUrls: ['./parent-of-sibling.component.css']
})
export class ParentOfSiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

> This is sibling.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
  <button (click)="newMessage()">Send message to parent</button>
`,  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM SIBLING")
  }

}
```

> And finally this is the data.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }

}
```

This works perfectly if I am communicating a string:
[image]
[image]
When I tried to communicate a number using the same code, the app gives an error.
So here are my questions:
1/ What is causing the error? (I.e: I do know that this code works for strings and not numbers but why does it only work for strings?)
2/ Is there any way to fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you include error? Note that `changeMessage` method accept only string at this point.

Comment: @Buczkowski Is there another method I can use instead of changeMessage? I will include the error in a second.  But, now thanks to you, I understand what's causing the error

Comment: Argument of type '4' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: Even if I change changeMessage to accept numbers it doesn't work

Comment: Because :     this.messageSource.next(message);
only accepts strings

Comment: You would need to change all the types to number not just the changeMessage method but also the default property of your BehaviorSubject needs to be a number, as well.

Comment: @Ahmed Ghrib it does because it inherits from default value that you provided - 'default message'. Try to change it to: `new BehaviorSubject<any>('default message');` or specify type.

Comment: @Buczkowski You're awesome. It works. I will post the answer in a second :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Buczkowski tip, I solved the issue.

```
export class DataService {
  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<Number>(4);
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
  constructor() { }
  changeMessage(message: Number) {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to modify the parent and sibling component accordingly. I mean change string to number